# Spark reduceByKey function seems not working with single one key

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a 5 row records in mysql, like

1. sku:001 seller:A stock:UK margin:10
2. sku:002 seller:B stock:US margin:5
3. sku:001 seller:A stock:UK margin:10
4. sku:001 seller:A stock:UK margin:3
5. sku:001 seller:A stock:UK margin:7

And I've this rows read into spark and transformed them into

```
JavaPairRDD<Tuple3<String,String,String>, Map>(<sku,seller,stock>, Map<margin,xxx>).
```

Seems like works fine until now.

However, When I used the reduceByKey function to sum the margin as the structure like:

```
JavaPairRDD<Tuple3<String,String,String>, Map>(<sku,seller,stock>, Map<marginSummary, xxx>).
```

the final result got 2 elements

```
JavaPairRDD<Tuple3<String,String,String>, Map>(<sku,seller,stock>, Map<margin,xxx>).
JavaPairRDD<Tuple3<String,String,String>, Map>(<sku,seller,stock>, Map<marginSummary, xxx>).
```

seems like the row2 didn't enter the reduceByKey function body. I was wondering why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected outcome. `func` is called only when objects for a single key are merged. If there is only one key, there is no reason to call it.

Unfortunately it looks like you have a bigger problem, which can be inferred from you question. You are trying to change the type of the value in `reduceByKey`. In general it shouldn't even compile as `reduceByKey` takes `Function2<V,V,V>` - input and output types have to be identical.

If you want to change a type, you should use either `combineByKey`

```
public <C> JavaPairRDD<K,C> combineByKey(Function<V,C> createCombiner,
                                     Function2<C,V,C> mergeValue,
                                     Function2<C,C,C> mergeCombiners)
```

or `aggregateByKey`

```
public <U> JavaPairRDD<K,U> aggregateByKey(U zeroValue,
                                       Function2<U,V,U> seqFunc,
                                       Function2<U,U,U> combFunc)
```

Both can change the types and fixed your current problem. Please refer to Java test suite for examples: [1](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4ba9c6c453606f5e5a1e324d5f933d2c9307a604/core/src/test/java/test/org/apache/spark/JavaAPISuite.java#L1261-L1288) and [2](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4ba9c6c453606f5e5a1e324d5f933d2c9307a604/core/src/test/java/test/org/apache/spark/JavaAPISuite.java#L519-L543).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I see what the "key problem" is now. Actually I've placed string in the value, stringfy from a JSONObject, marginSummary is just one attribute of severals in it.